# Generating a random order for specific numbers with ECMA 5.1 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

We created a JavaScript with ECMA 6 syntax which creates an array randomly listing the 4 numbers between 1-5. Here is our code:

```
// function to pick length number between min and max
function generateRandomArr(length, max, min) {
  const resultsArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    resultsArr.includes(newNumber) ? length += 1 : resultsArr.push(newNumber);
  }
  return resultsArr;
}


// picks 4 digits between 1 and 5 and stores them in an array
vars.listsarray = generateRandomArr(4, 5, 1);

console.log ("List of 4 digits picked: "+vars.listsarray)

console.log("Set task order for subject_nr "+vars.subject_nr)
```

The problem is that the software we will use uses ECMA 5.1 syntax. Is there a way to accomplish the same task in ECMA 5.1?

Comment: What is `vars`? What is `vars.subject_nr`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `const`s and `let`s with `var`. You can use [this](https://es6console.com/) tool to transpile your javascript in the future (that's what I used for convenience)

```js
// function to pick length number between min and max
"use strict";

function generateRandomArr(length, max, min) {
  var resultsArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    resultsArr.includes(newNumber) ? length += 1 : resultsArr.push(newNumber);
  }
  return resultsArr;
}

var vars = {}
// picks 4 digits between 1 and 5 and stores them in an array
vars.listsarray = generateRandomArr(4, 5, 1);

console.log("List of 4 digits picked: " + vars.listsarray);

console.log("Set task order for subject_nr " + vars.subject_nr);
```